# How do I create a global variable in Geddy

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, global-variables, geddy

I'm like to define a global variable `box` that is available in all controllers across my app in Geddy. How would one go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a global variable in: /config/**secrets.json**. If you don't have this secret yet it can be generate using:

```
geddy gen secret
```

And then add below to the secret.json.

```
{
    "box": "value of box"
}
```

And value can be used **geddy.config.box**